# AJAX - Parsing JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am attempting to match an id of a table cell with an id specified within a JSON file. If a match is found I will later do something with the description. Everytime this is ran, it skips straight to the error message. What am I doing wrong?

```
function getJSON(showID){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'json/tvshows.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key,tvshow){
                tvshow.description;
                var tvshowId = tvshow.id;

                if (tvshowId == showID) {
                    var description = tvshow.description;
                    console.log(description);
                }
            })
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('Error occured in getDescription');
        }   
    }); //Ends ajax request 
}
```

Comment: Does `tvshow` contains with JSON value?

Comment: If you're seeing the message in the error handler it means that there was a problem with the request retrieving the JSON. Are you running on your local filesystem? If so the request will be blocked by the browsers' security. You need to test AJAX on an actual webserver.

Comment: make sure that the url is correct.

Comment: Try `error:function(er){ console.log(er); }` to see what the error is.

Comment: Since you're not going cross-domain, why do you need to use JSONP instead of JSON?

Answer (score 0):

you should be using:

```
dataType: 'json',
```